# Allow user to resize android control

Tags: android, xamarin

I am working on an android app where i am planning to show weather details. Apart from weather details there will be another control which will show the latest news. What i am planning to do is if user could somehow resize this weather and news control in the app and also through touch gesture place these two controls anywhere in the app.

I am planning to use Xamarin but open to suggestions.

I have been googling to find the best possible way to achieve this but could not find any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Drag and Drop by following steps:

1. Create your xaml file with `AbsoluteLayout`:

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light">
        <Button
         android:id="@+id/btnDrapDrop"
         android:layout_width="200dp"
         android:layout_height="50dp"
         android:text="Button To Drag"/>


    </AbsoluteLayout>
   ```
2. Register the Long Click event of the button as the Drag and Drop event and call `View.StartDrag` in the event:

   ```
    Button btnDrapDrop;
    ...
    btnDrapDrop.LongClick += BtnDrapDrop_LongClick;
    ...
    private void BtnDrapDrop_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ClipData dragData = ClipData.NewPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(btnDrapDrop);
        btnDrapDrop.StartDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
    }
   ```
3. Register the `Drag` event of the `AbsoluteLayout` to receive the drop and translate the button when user drops:

   ```
    AbsoluteLayout layout;
    ...
    layout.Drag += BtnDrapDrop_Drag;
    ...
    private void BtnDrapDrop_Drag(object sender, View.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        AbsoluteLayout layout = (AbsoluteLayout)sender;

        switch (e.Event.Action)
        {
            case DragAction.Drop:
                float x=e.Event.GetX();
                float y = e.Event.GetY();
                btnDrapDrop.TranslationX = x;
                btnDrapDrop.TranslationY = y;
                layout.Invalidate();
                return;
        }
    }
   ```

Here is the complete Activity:

The event will work when you long press the Button .

```
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    Button btnDrapDrop;
    AbsoluteLayout layout;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Second);
        btnDrapDrop=FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnDrapDrop);
        layout = FindViewById<AbsoluteLayout>(Resource.Id.layout);
        
        //register the  long click event of drap button
        btnDrapDrop.LongClick += BtnDrapDrop_LongClick;
        //register the drag event of the layout
        layout.Drag += BtnDrapDrop_Drag;
    }

    private void BtnDrapDrop_Drag(object sender, View.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        AbsoluteLayout layout = (AbsoluteLayout)sender;

        switch (e.Event.Action)
        {
            case DragAction.Drop:
                float x=e.Event.GetX();
                float y = e.Event.GetY();
                btnDrapDrop.TranslationX = x;
                btnDrapDrop.TranslationY = y;
                layout.Invalidate();
                return;
        }
    }

    private void BtnDrapDrop_LongClick(object sender, Android.Views.View.LongClickEventArgs e)
    {
        ClipData dragData = ClipData.NewPlainText("", "");
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadow = new View.DragShadowBuilder(btnDrapDrop);
        btnDrapDrop.StartDrag(dragData, myShadow, null, 0);
    }
}
```

For Details of Drap and Drop in Android, please refer to [Drag and Drop](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/drag-drop.html).